# Database Migration from sqlite to room expected table handling

Tags: java, android, android-room

I keep getting this error and I still don't know how to solve it. Please help me out here. This are my error Logs :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: task(com.examples.TaskEntry).

 Expected:
    TableInfo{name='task', columns={description=Column{name='description', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, priority=Column{name='priority', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, updated_at=Column{name='updated_at', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}


Found:
    TableInfo{name='task', columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

Below is my TaskEntry Entity Class where I presume all the problem originates from:

```
@Entity(tableName = "task")
public class TaskEntry {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    @NonNull
    private String description;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "priority")
    private int priority;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Ignore
    public TaskEntry(@NonNull String description, int priority, Date updatedAt) {
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public TaskEntry(int id, @NonNull String description, int priority, Date updatedAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }
```

In this code I manage to call the Migration instance to my Room Database Class:

```
final static Migration MIGRATION_5_6 = new Migration(5, 6) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.


    }
};

public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Creating new database instance");
            sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    AppDatabase.class, AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_5_6)
                    .addCallback(roomCallback)


                    .build();
        }
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting the database instance");
```

Comment: Finally solved it by changing the db name. For some reasons when named the same as the sqlite open helper it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, Room has found a database  that has no **task** table, hence there being no columns, foreign keys or indicies.

> Below is my TaskEntry Entity Class where I presume all the problem originates from:

This would only be the issue, I beleive, if the table name in the database is not **task** e.g. if the table were named tasks and `@Entity(tableName = "task")` were used instead of @Entity(tableName = "tasks")`

Otherwise the issue would appear to perhaps be in the Migration. Perhaps by saying  */ Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.* What is actually happening is that you are introducing the table (otherwsie if not adding or introducing the table why would there be a migration). If that were the case then the Migration should be :-

```
final static Migration MIGRATION_5_6 = new Migration(5, 6) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `task` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `description` TEXT NOT NULL, `priority` INTEGER NOT NULL, `updated_at` TEXT)");
    }
};
```

- Note the SQL has been copied from the **createAllTables** method in the  **AppDatabase_Impl.java** in the generated Java after compiling (but not running the App).

However, you would likely then get an error :-

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

So you would need to eitherr change the **updateAt** column to be a type of **String** or Write and Implement a TypeConverter.